# Atomically changing the credentials in c3p0 ComboPooledDataSource

Tags: java, credentials, c3p0

The c3p0 `ComboPooledDataSource` has two methods for setting credentials, `setUser` and `setPassword`.  My software will periodically rotate username and password for db access, and I'm concerned that between the calls to setUser and setPassword queries will be made and fail because of the credential mismatch.

I don't see a combined setter method on the object

[ComboPooledDataSource Docs](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/ComboPooledDataSource.html)

Anyone with experience here that knows whether I'm worried over nothing or whether there is a method to doing this?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to set them both at once, you can use the `setProperties(...)` method, with JDBC standard keys `user` and `password`.